# Program Open/ Save As Dialogue No Bookmarks No Places

Tags: files, cinnamon, nemo, pcmanfm

I thought I had solved this before but can't remember what I did.

I use Qpdfview for my PDF viewer.  The Save As/ Open dialogue does not have any bookmarks or places like the default file manager (NEMO).  I have Nemo and PCManFM installed and am using Cinnamon desktop on an Lubuntu 16.04 install.

So - is there a way to change the file mangager on the left (default program FM) so that it functions like the one on the right? (Nemo or PCManFM) (see screenshot)

Thanks[image]